# EXCEL Заполнение одной таблицы из другой по идентификатору

Tags: excel

В общем, есть одна таблица, уже стандартизированная для экспорта в бд, но надо из другой добавить комментарии к нужному элементу из первой.
Пример первой таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример второй таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как видите, первая таблица разбита по уровням. Необходимо в колонку "O" добавить комментарии (колонка "U") из второй таблицы, где совпадают id (во второй - колонка "S"). 
Пробовал ВПР - не получается.

Comment: Странно, ВПР() на таких данных должен работать хорошо, он именно для таких ситуаций и предназначен. А как ВПР() выглядел и на что он ругался?

Comment: @JohnSUN , если правильно помню, то ошибка в основном была #Н/Д. Оно то работало, но я не понимаю как именно ее использовать, ведь мне надо указать несколько искомых значений.

Comment: Покажите, как "не получается". Возможно, потому, что в первой таблице `ID` находятся в разных столбцах. Попутно (на #Н/Д не влияет): в столбце `U` во второй таблице пусто.

Comment: А, это обычно бывает из-за ошибки в четвёртом параметре - тип поиска. Если его не указывать, то считается, что он 1 и поиск ведётся приближённо и считается, что первая колонка отсортирована по возрастанию. Лучше его указать явно как ЛОЖЬ. Другая причина, из-за которой можно получить #Н/Д - лишние пробелы или в колонке S второй таблицы или в C, E, G и т.д. в первой таблице - мы их не видим, а они там есть, поэтому и поиск не срабатывает.

Comment: Ах да, забыл упомянуть ещё одну распространённую ошибку - адрес диапазона, в котором ищем значение лучше задать с **абсолютным адресом** (со знаками $ перед имен колонок и номерами строк, задаётся нажатием F4). Для одной ячейки формула с относительным адресом работает хорошо, а после растягивания адрес диапазона меняется и поиск возвращает #Н/Д потому что ищет уже не в том месте.